# is relativity an illusion , a measuring error?

Tags: relativity

In the proof of relativity through lorenz transformation it looks like the relativity is essentially a mis of accuracy to measure the time and lengths. Am I true?

Comment: No, it's totally wrong. measures are precises, but depends on the referential.

Comment: Well.. it was a "something" like a miss of "accuracy" to measure the time and length, but it was due to a miss on understanding the concept of inertial frame and simultaneity. Einstein left very clear we were very dumbs to believe that time is absolute to any inertial frame of reference, but we already apologized for this and move on.

Answer (score 2):

No. It is not about any measurement error or the wrong measurements being carried out by some observer or something. Relativity is about the actual changes that come when you change the frame of reference. It is the heart of relativity that all the observers are equivalent and thus surely it doesn't suggest that the 'moving' observers carry out 'wrong' experiments.

The basis of relativity theory comes from 3 things:
2 postulates of Einstein (1. All inertial frames are equivalent 2. The speed of light is same in all inertial frames.) and the definition of simultaneity.

Definition of simultaneity essentially determines what you call a tick of your clock and length of your meter stick and using that definition one can derive the Lorentz Transformations.

Definition of simultaneity clearly states that chronological order of events may be different for different observers and thus simultaneity is relative - and of course, each one's simultaneity is as valid as the other one's. And thus the measurements of the time interval and length also differs in different frames and all of them are equally justified and all the difference that comes is very fundamental- namely a consequence of the most intuitive definition of simultaneity. It is not about experimental errors.

Rather what relativity suggests is that the reality is not 3 dimensional as our intuition suggests, but it is 4 dimensional. The distance between 2 points (i.e. events) in this 4-dimensional reality is to be measured by $c^2t^2 - x^2 - y^2 - z^2$, which essentially comes out same in all the inertial frames. But the individual of these terms: $t, x, y,$ or $z$ can be different for different observers. And all of them are equally justified.

Comment: When you talk about the Einstein's postulates, you are talking about special relativity. You should be clear on this

Comment: Yes. OP had asked in context of Lorentz Transformation, so I thought the context is to be presumed to be special relativity.